# Conditions for the logarithm of a symmetric positive definite matrix to be positive definite

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, matrix-calculus

Say I have a square symmetric positive definite matrix $M \in R^n \times R^n$. If I want the matrix A obtained after the following transformation:

$$ a_{ij} = \log(m_{ij}) \ \forall i,j \ \ \text{if} \ \ m_{ij} \neq 0 $$
$$ a_{ij} = 0 \ \text{otherwise} $$

to be positive definite, do I need extra conditions on the matrix A or M ?

Edit: $m_{ij} \geq 0 \ \forall i,j$

Comment: What is $a_{ij}$ if $m_{ij}<0$?

Comment: If $n=1$ the identity matrix is a square symmetric positive definite matrix, but the transformation doesn't preserve that property, so the answer is yes

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that you mean $a_{ij} = log(m_{ij}) \ \forall i,j \ \ \text{if} \ \ m_{ij} > 0.$

Consider the case $n=2$ with $m_{11}=e, m_{12}=m_{21}=0$ and $m_{22}=e^{-1}.$ Then $M$ is positive definite, but

$$A=\begin{pmatrix}
      1 & 0\\
       0 & -1
    \end{pmatrix}$$

is indefinite.